# How to take the derivative of this matrix formula with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have the following code

```
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, Matrix
from sympy import *

# Equation for line P = P0 + t*Pv
P0 = MatrixSymbol('P0',3,1)
Pv = MatrixSymbol('Pv',3,1)
t = symbols('t')
P = P0 + t*Pv 

# Cone origin and axis
A0 = MatrixSymbol('A0',3,1)
Av = MatrixSymbol('Av',3,1)
K = (P - A0)

Q = K.T*Av
R = sqrt((K.T*K-Q.T*Q))

# components for the cone normal
sin, cos = symbols('sin cos')

KK = -sin*Q + cos*R

KKd = KK.diff(t)

print(KKd)
```

The above code is part of the logic for trying to figure the closest point on a segment to the cone. However that puzzle is not specifically relevant. The question is why do I keep getting the below error with the above code? I get the same error with

```
R.diff(t)
```

which fails but

```
K.diff(t)
```

and

```
Q.diff(t)
```

and

```
(K.T*K-Q.T*Q).diff(t)
```

do not fail. So I think the problem is with the construction of the square root. However after `(K.T*K-Q.T*Q)` the result should be a scalar so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\brad\Downloads\cone2.py", line 23, in <module>
    KKd = KK.diff(t)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 3502, in diff
    return _derivative_dispatch(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 1946, in _derivative_dispatch
    return ArrayDerivative(expr, *variables, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 17, in __new__
    obj = super().__new__(cls, expr, *variables, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 1473, in __new__
    obj = cls._dispatch_eval_derivative_n_times(expr, v, count)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 106, in _dispatch_eval_derivative_n_times
    result = cls._call_derive_matexpr_by_scalar(expr, v)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 66, in _call_derive_matexpr_by_scalar
    return expr._eval_derivative(v)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\expressions\matexpr.py", line 220, in _eval_derivative
    return super()._eval_derivative(x)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 74, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\add.py", line 498, in _eval_derivative
    return self.func(*[a.diff(s) for a in self.args])
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\add.py", line 498, in <listcomp>
    return self.func(*[a.diff(s) for a in self.args])
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 3502, in diff
    return _derivative_dispatch(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 1946, in _derivative_dispatch
    return ArrayDerivative(expr, *variables, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 17, in __new__
    obj = super().__new__(cls, expr, *variables, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 1473, in __new__
    obj = cls._dispatch_eval_derivative_n_times(expr, v, count)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 106, in _dispatch_eval_derivative_n_times
    result = cls._call_derive_matexpr_by_scalar(expr, v)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 66, in _call_derive_matexpr_by_scalar
    return expr._eval_derivative(v)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\expressions\matexpr.py", line 220, in _eval_derivative
    return super()._eval_derivative(x)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 74, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\mul.py", line 977, in _eval_derivative
    d = args[i].diff(s)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 3502, in diff
    return _derivative_dispatch(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 1946, in _derivative_dispatch
    return ArrayDerivative(expr, *variables, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 17, in __new__
    obj = super().__new__(cls, expr, *variables, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 1473, in __new__
    obj = cls._dispatch_eval_derivative_n_times(expr, v, count)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 106, in _dispatch_eval_derivative_n_times
    result = cls._call_derive_matexpr_by_scalar(expr, v)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\array\array_derivatives.py", line 66, in _call_derive_matexpr_by_scalar
    return expr._eval_derivative(v)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\expressions\matpow.py", line 93, in _eval_derivative
    return Pow._eval_derivative(self, x)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\power.py", line 1322, in _eval_derivative
    return self * (dexp * log(self.base) + dbase * self.exp/self.base)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\numbers.py", line 2165, in __add__
    return Rational.__add__(self, other)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\decorators.py", line 95, in __sympifyit_wrapper
    return func(a, b)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\numbers.py", line 1708, in __add__
    return Number.__add__(self, other)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\decorators.py", line 95, in __sympifyit_wrapper
    return func(a, b)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\numbers.py", line 724, in __add__
    return AtomicExpr.__add__(self, other)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\decorators.py", line 266, in _func
    return func(self, other)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\decorators.py", line 135, in binary_op_wrapper
    return f(self)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\expressions\matexpr.py", line 29, in __sympifyit_wrapper
    return func(a, b)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\decorators.py", line 136, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(self, other)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\expressions\matexpr.py", line 113, in __radd__
    return MatAdd(other, self, check=True).doit()
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\expressions\matadd.py", line 51, in __new__
    validate(*args)
  File "c:\users\brad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\expressions\matadd.py", line 93, in validate
    raise TypeError("Mix of Matrix and Scalar symbols")
TypeError: Mix of Matrix and Scalar symbols
```

Comment: I'll just leave this as a comment. I couldn't find a way to do it without breaking up the matrix symbols. That is, have something like `P0 = MatrixSymbol('P0',3,1).as_explicit()` for each matrix symbol you define. Note that 1x1 matrices are not considered scalars in SymPy and so the final result will be a 1x1 matrix. It might also be a good idea to check out `sympy.vectors` or `sympy.physics.vectors` but again, both of those don't really have matrix symbols AFAICT.